# Take X Symbols After a Marker and Save to Variable in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm looking for a way via AppleScript to take 11 symbols after `?v=` part in an URL that's in clipboard and save them into a variable. Here's an example of a link:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxDK95Q5qN0&ab_channel=TheLateShowwithStephenColbert
```

So I need a little script that would take a link in clipboard, identify 11 symbols after `?v=`, take those 11 symbols (`PxDK95Q5qN0`) from that link and save it into a variable (e.g. extract).

I did find a partial solution [here](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24725) — but that one only works when it's BETWEEN two parts e.g. `?v=` and `&`. The problem with that solution is that many links are short and do not have the last & symbol (e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxDK95Q5qN0`)

I'd appreciate any help or pointers here! :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you set the clipboard to, e.g.,:

```
set the clipboard to "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxDK95Q5qN0&ab_channel=TheLateShowwithStephenColbert"
```

Or, e.g.,:

```
set the clipboard to "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxDK95Q5qNO"
```

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* returns the eleven characters after `?v=`:

```
set extract to do shell script ¬
    "sed -Ee 's/.*[?]v[=]([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11}).*/\\1/'<<<" & ¬
    (the clipboard as text)'s quoted form
```

- Note that `\\?v\\=` can be used instead of the `[?]v[=]` portion of the `sed` *command* as in either case the `?` and `=` are treated as *regular characters* instead of *shell special characters*.
- Additionally, if the number of target characters changes from 11 yet `?v=` and `&` are still in play, as in your examples, then this *regex*, with explanation shown further below, handles it:

  `.*[?]v[=]([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[^&]).*`

---

**Notes**:

If the 11 target characters contain other than what is shown in the *capturing group*:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})
```

Then modify it as needed.

---

Using info from https://regex101.com to explain the *regex* used in the `sed` *command*:

The main part of interest is the **Capturing Group** `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})`, as this is what's returned, if it exists directly after `?v=` in the **URL**.

[image]

---

When **Capturing Group** is: `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)`

[image]

Comment: The `count of characters of extract` currently returns `23`. By omitting the trailing `p` flag from the [`s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) it returns the correct result. I changed it to `sed -E 's/.*[?][v][=]([a-xA-Z0-9]{11}).*/\\1/'` - Note the `p` flag was omitted because that was also printing the pattern space. I also removed the `-e` option. _(Note: I was using BSD SED)_

Comment: @RobC, I totally missed that in testing, the `p` has been removed, thanks!

Comment: @user10460848, I had a typo in the `sed` cmd of my answer when you accepted it, sorry, I've since updated the answer, please have a look and use the corrected _code_, thanks.

Comment: @RobC — thanks so much, your fix to user3439894's initial answer really did the trick! user3439894 — thank you for writing up the initial anwer as well as for updating it. All — guys, you're amazing, THANK YOU for taking the time to reply. I really am learning a lot here and polishing my AppleScript AND shell skills! Much, much obliged!

Comment: It's not specified in the question but some youtube url video strings include '-' or '_', which would not be handled by the above code (e.g. 3_zLyE8eIUo, Hfhl-hOlb2Y).

Comment: @Mockman, Yes, '-' or '_' was not shown or even mentioned in the OP, however, I've updated the answer to include the two aforementioned characters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That macsripter link points you in the right direction (though it's a lot of information to digest). As long as you're running 10.6 or later, you can use this routine:

```
on getTheV(link_text)
    set {tid, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, {"=", "&"}}
    set theV to second text item of link_text
    set my text item delimiters to tid
    return theV
end getTheV
```

which breaks the link up into text items — split on '=' and '&' — and returns the second item.

Use it like so:

```
set theV to getTheV("http://...")
```

Both the links you provided return the correct value.